# List of houses parcel number US

Tags: data-request, real-estate

Some government sites or real estate sites like zillow, provide a parcel number for houses which seems to be a unique identifier for that house; is there a site where I can find a list of all parcel numbers in US?

Answer (score 3):

[Assessors Parcel numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assessor%27s_parcel_number) in the US are assigned within specific jurisdictions (usually counties, which are smaller than states and often larger than cities or towns). Within a single jurisdiction they will have a consistent format and be unique, but across multiple jurisdictions you have no such guarantee and will likely see a fair amount of variance in formatting (see, for example, the different formats used by [Fresno County](http://www2.co.fresno.ca.us/0420/pcortutorial/Parcel_Numbers.pdf), [Warren County Missouri](http://www.warrencountymo.org/collector/UNDERSTANDING%20R%20E%20PARCEL%20ID%20NUMBER%20-%202009.pdf), and [Clark County Nevada](http://www.clarkcountynv.gov/assessor/Pages/ParcelandMapNumberingSystem.aspx)).

To my knowledge there is no single source of parcel data across the entire country, you will mostly have to look up the particular jurisdiction you're interested in, but there is a significant amount of [federated parcel data on data.gov](https://catalog.data.gov/dataset?q=parcel&sort=score%20desc%2C%20name%20asc&as_sfid=AAAAAAXLxrRhnAGVVYdjgOT6BuDolJ2DfOsy8PN3j2ka8227YKQshqiiGaVlXZ18xfVSEfzyUay_lcZRbthpAHPb_KJq-klzxlpGqXqury4g3FxM9qGYkIe9NuAYKYCMY7AC1VE%3D&as_fid=e662e4593d84ff83c1594aff766b7a7661dd36f8&ext_location=&ext_bbox=&ext_prev_extent=-142.03125%2C8.754794702435618%2C-59.0625%2C61.77312286453146) provided by cities, states, and counties.

You may have more luck identifying individual properties by geocoding street addresses and using census data -- but both of these have their limits depending on the granularity and quality of data available.

Answer (score 0):

[Open Addresses](https://openaddresses.io/) focuses on street centerlines data, but they are collecting parcels data as well. I'm not 100% who to contact or where the parcels data is being collected, but would be worth your time to reach out to them and get access to what they have.